# Shell script to find and replace string patten after exclude mutiple pattern

Tags: bash, shell, sed, grep

I need to change below details:

1. Search each shell file, each line contains "echo" or "echo -e" (before or after echo may have spaces) replace to "logger" which contains redirection to another file
2. If a line contains only "echo" also have to replace by "logger"
3. "\n" or "\t" replace to empty space in each line
4. Find " 2>&1" and remove until end of line

But "echo" exists in other places should not be changed. Other places means:

1. Inside sqlplus set echo on or
2. echo variable to cut or assign to another variable etc.

Sample File: run.sh

```
1   echo "**********************"   2>&1 | tee -a  out.log
2   echo -e "**********************\n"   2>&1 | tee -a  out.log
3   
4   NBD=`sqlplus $dbconnection <<EOF | grep '^-' | sed 's/-//'
5   cl scr;
6   set serveroutput on;
7   set echo off;
8   set head off;
9   set termout off
10  set verify off
11  set feedback off
12  cl scr;
13  select '-'||sysdate from dual;
14  exit;
15  EOF`
16  
17  Error_code=`echo $?`
18  echo 
19  file_name=$1
20  
21  echo spoolfile = $file_name
22  echo $spoolfile
23  echo $spoolfile |cut -d'|' -f4 | read str4
24   echo 
25  exit 0
```

Expected Output: run_new.sh
Modified lines: 1,2, 18, 24

```
1   logger "**********************"
2   logger -e "**********************"
3   
4   NBD=`sqlplus $dbconnection <<EOF | grep '^-' | sed 's/-//'
5   cl scr;
6   set serveroutput on;
7   set echo off;
8   set head off;
9   set termout off
10  set verify off
11  set feedback off
12  cl scr;
13  select '-'||sysdate from dual;
14  exit;
15  EOF`
16  
17  Error_code=`echo $?`
18  logger
19  file_name=$1
20  
21  echo spoolfile = $file_name
22  echo $spoolfile
23  echo $spoolfile |cut -d'|' -f4 | read str4
24   logger
25  exit 0
```

I tried below:

```
shell_find_tee="2>&1"
f_in=run.sh
f_out=run_new.sh
# To remove line contains: $shell_find_tee
sed -e "s/$shell_find_tee.*//g" < $f_in > $f_out

#To find "echo" or "echo -e" replace by "logger"
shell_find_echo_main="echo"
shell_find_echo_main_e="echo.*-e"
shell_replace_echo="logger"

sed -e "s@$shell_find_echo_main_e@$shell_replace_echo@g" -e "s@$shell_find_echo_main@$shell_replace_echo@g" < $f_in > $f_out
```

But these commands replace all "echo" by "logger" and I don't know how to exclude string patter in "sed" command or any other ways.

Could someone please help me?

Comment: Why shouldn't lines 21 and 22 be replaced? They don't seem to correspond to your two exceptions.

Comment: @Aaron - Line 21 echo the variable and echo to

Comment: @Aaron - Line 21 echo the variable and Line 22: echo  assign to another variable which should be not replaced.

Comment: So you ONLY want to replace `echo` when it's standalone, not when it's actually echoing a variable or anything? Then what does your requirement `1` mean given your requirement `2` describes the standalone case? Requirement 3 says to replace `"\n"` with a space (blank char?) but the only place `"\n"` occurs in your input (line 2) you completely remove it in the output. Clarify.

Comment: Specifically clarify why `echo "**********************"` on line 1 become `logger "**********************"` while `echo $spoolfile` on line 22 doesn't change.

Comment: @Maran your example in your question shows `echo -e` on line 2 in the input becoming `logger -e` in the output so why are you now saying in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52001148/shell-script-to-find-and-replace-string-patten-after-exclude-mutiple-pattern#comment90954381_52002157) that `echo -e` should become just `logger` without the `-e`? You REALLY need to take another look at your requirements and the example you provided if you'd like help as your question right now is just a bunch of confusing contradictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like this:

1. Find lines which start with `(spaces)?echo( -e)?`

   1. If they contain only `echo` or `echo -e`

      1. Replace `echo` with `logger`
   2. If the line also contains `2>&1`

      1. Replace the leading echo with logger
      2. Replace `\t` or `\n` with single space
      3. Remove everything after `2>&1`

```
sed '
/^[[:space:]]*echo\([[:space:]]\+-e\)\?/{
     /^[[:space:]]*echo[[:space:]]\+\([[:space:]]\+-e\)\?[[:space:]]*$/{
           s/^\([[:space:]]*\)echo/\1logger/;
     };
     /2>&1/{
           s/^\([[:space:]]*\)echo/\1logger/;
           s/\\[tn]/ /g;
           s/[[:space:]]*2>&1.*//;
     }
 }'
```

For the tests cases seems to work:

```
diff <(cat run.sh | cut -c5-) <(cat run.sh | cut -c5- | sed '
    /^[[:space:]]*echo\([[:space:]]\+-e\)\?/{
         /^[[:space:]]*echo[[:space:]]\+\([[:space:]]\+-e\)\?[[:space:]]*$/{
               s/^\([[:space:]]*\)echo/\1logger/;
         };
         /2>&1/{
               s/^\([[:space:]]*\)echo/\1logger/;
               s/\\[tn]/ /g;
               s/[[:space:]]*2>&1.*//;
         }
     }')
1,2c1,2
< echo "**********************"   2>&1 | tee -a  out.log
< echo -e "**********************\n"   2>&1 | tee -a  out.log
---
> logger "**********************"
> logger -e "********************** "
18c18
< echo 
---
> logger 
24c24
<  echo 
---
>  logger
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your commands works fine. I am sorry, my bad, I forgot to mention earlier  that1)  if "echo -e" or "echo" should replaced to "logger"  (without -e) and 2) This command not works only in case.... esac conditions. output of case ... esac part as follows:   Error_code=`echo $?`
    case $Error_code in
  0) echo  "OK" 2>&1 | tee -a  out.log             
           logger "Date: "$(date)
           ;;   
        *) echo  "\033[41m NOT OK\033[0m" 2>&1 | tee -a  out.log 
;;
    esac

Comment: Maybe then search for a strings like `echo (-e)? "<anything>" 2>&1`. And add more test cases to the question. Unless you will not decide what you want, there's nothing we can do. If the echos in your source files are not any particular special, you need to go through all the sources and change all the lines yourself. You can also train and implement a neural network to do the work for you, but... is it worth it?

Comment: Again thank you so much. You are command worked fine with my minor modification to handle the "case" part.